# There is some way to intercept a GraphQL Query schema validation error?

Tags: c#, .net, graphql

I have GraphQL Schema that accepts a query like this:

```
query () {
   Customers() {
      Id
      Age
   }
}
```

If the caller requests a non existing field, like "Birthday" in the following example:

```
query () {
   Customers() {
      Id
      Age
      Birthday
   }
}
```

The .NET GraphQL library automatically returns an error to the caller in the response:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "GraphQL.Validation.Errors.FieldsOnCorrectTypeError: Cannot query field \"Birthday\" on type \"CustomerType\". Did you mean \"Age\" or \"Name\"?",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 4,
                    "column": 13
                }
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "code": "FIELDS_ON_CORRECT_TYPE",
                "codes": [
                    "FIELDS_ON_CORRECT_TYPE"
                ],
                "number": "5.3.1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I get this error (that JSON object) in my backend code? I'd like to log this error or check what field is being searched.